# WPF threads and tasks on textchanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

**Using Visual Studio 2012 ulti, C# .NET  WPF.**

Using Tasks in my code on winforms used to be simple.

All I would do is create a delegate, create a function for my code, create a task and the event would be a simple button. Easy stuff.  Problem I  have is the following...

- Create a thread as per-usual But the **event** will be on **text changed**.

The problem im having is thinking about the logic, if I simply change the event I cant see this working as the user could type faster than the code could run ( in this case an sql query select statement). There for it would try to run many tasks which I don't even think would work.

Basically User enters text box that used for searching an account by name or number.
In this textbox I would like to thread the entire process.

The only solution I can think of is as the text changes **if** there is a **thread still running stop that thread** and **create the new one**, but not sure if thats a clean way of doing it as its a sql stored procedure ill be calling.

So any body got a solution to this?

If you need any more info just ask.  Ill also provide some code that currently works  to give you an understanding if needed...

**Set Invoke method up:**

```
private void SetDataGrid(bool AutoGenerateColumns, Object DataSource, String DataMember, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode Mode)
    {
        if (this.ParetoGrid.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.ParetoGrid.Invoke(new Action<bool, Object, String, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode>(SetDataGrid),
                                      AutoGenerateColumns, DataSource, DataMember, Mode);
        }
        else
        {
            this.ParetoGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = AutoGenerateColumns;
            this.ParetoGrid.DataSource = DataSource;
            this.ParetoGrid.DataMember = DataMember;
            ParetoGrid.AutoResizeColumns(Mode);
        }
    }
```

**Call invoke method in another method:**

```
Private void GetSomething()
{
    //sql code get data
    SetDataGrid(true, dataSet1, "Pareto", DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
}
```

**Then simply start task on event:**

```
private void myButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task t = new Task(() => getSomething());
    t.Start();
}
```

As you can see simple stuff, but simple changing event seems to mess the whole logic up.

Comment: `my code on winforms used to be simple.` - Not true. winforms doesn't allow a clear and true separation of UI and application logic / data and thus forces you into a bunch of horrible hacks for almost anything. WPF + MVVM is clean, beautiful and scalable. Admittedly, non-MVVM WPF can be painful, but why would you do that?

Comment: well this is my first app using wpf, was just wandering if i can use old win-forms code modify slightly to wpf.

Comment: not really. You `could` do that, but again, WPF is much more beautiful and pleasant to work with if you use the MVVM pattern, and not a horrible bunch of crappy hacks coming from the winforms' inability to separate UI and logic.

Comment: And by the way, MVVM teaches you to forget `events` for almost everything. Why would you handle `TextBox.TextChanged`? Instead, you bind the `TextBox.Text` to some property in the ViewModel, and react in the setter of the property. That's what I mean by separation of UI and logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recomend moving this logic from the task into a `Timer` callback, then have your `OnTextChanged` handler actually reset the timer each time it's fired (only have the timer fire once of course). By making the timer elapse after .5-1 sec, or something like that, you'll wait until all of their text has been entered before actually calling your logic. But the user's experience will still be quite responsive.

Example:

```
private System.Threading.Timer keyEntryTimer = new Timer(Logic,null,-1,-1);

public void HandleEvent(objet sender, EventArgs args)
{
    keyEntryTimer.Change(500,-1);
}

public void Logic(objet state)
{
    //Your task logic would go here to read from the text etc... 
    //You'll have to handle any UI updates either by firing off a task once the DB results return or using a dispatcher
}
```

Comment: one of my mates just suggested a similar thing but not sure on the timers, i always thought threads and timers were extremely difficult to use together but i suppose its how you implement both in the logic.  could you provide an example of what you mean so i can start playing around testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cache all accounts when they enter this search mode. Then you can search through cached accounts when they enter text into the textbox. Doing a query in a different thread for every keypress is very heavy on the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do a combination of the other suggested answers and try to delay the firing of the SQL statement using a timer or some similar method, but if the user delayed long enough for the SQL to fire then try to just filter the returned results from that point forward (only if the search string is becoming more restrictive obviously).  This could save you expensive SQL round trips and give you a working cache after the first hit (which should be smaller than if you tried to cache everything).

Hope this helps.